# Yii2, как вывести во view данные из другой модели/таблицы?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

У меня есть 3 таблицы со связью многие-ко-многим.
Здесь код, который отвечает за отображение во view-файле:

```
    <?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'scientist_id',
        'scientist_name',
        'scientist_surname',
        'scientist_patronymic',            
        'scientist_additional_information:ntext',
        'field_id', //отображает поле, но не соответствующие айдишники
    ],
]) ?>
```

Мне нужно отображать во view-файле соответствующие field_id к scientist_id из таблицы (класса/модели) Summary_field. Как это сделать?

[image: scientst table and other]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто указать через точку

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'scientist_id',
        'scientist_name',
        'scientist_surname',
        'scientist_patronymic',            
        'scientist_additional_information:ntext',
        'Summary_field.field_id', //где Summary_field название связи в моделе
    ],
]) ?>
```

Или использовать ананимную функцию, где можно вернуть все что вы посчитаете нужным, можите использовать связь, можете использовать другую функцию

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'scientist_id',
        'scientist_name',
        'scientist_surname',
        'scientist_patronymic',            
        'scientist_additional_information:ntext',
        [
            'attribute'=>'field_id',
            'content'=>function($model){
                return $model->summary_field->field_id  //где Summary_field название связи в моделе
            }
        ]
    ],
]) ?>
```

Comment: Я сделал немного по-другому: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361263/yii2-how-to-use-another-model-for-display-in-view-file/35376544#35376544